# how to run a shell command at the END of the Android.mk build process?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am trying to copy a file from libs/arm/eabi in to res/raw at the end of the NDK build process using Android.mk

From some searching, I found that you can run a shell command to copy the file, like this:

```
$(shell cp $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/armeabi/pcapd res/raw)
```

However, even if I put this at the end of my top-most Android.mk, it always tries to run this command first.  How can I get it to run this after the build completes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27704875/894872

Answer (score 2):

You can add to your Android.mk before #include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE):

```
LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD := \
         cp $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../libs/armeabi/pcapd res/raw
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a makefile that calls ndk-build and then your shell line. Build your project by executing `make`

Comment: That will work, but I was hoping for something Android native. Thanks!

Comment: It's not possible with NDK's makefiles and it's not necessary. Why would you hope for it when it is using `make` anyway. Wrapper makefile is ideal to copy files around after build has completed.