# Execute shell command tar into android.mk

Tags: android, shell, makefile, tar

I want to extract a .tar.gz file using tar command into android.mk file. I already try this following android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

MY_LOCAL_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../..

$(shell tar xvzf $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)/abc.tar.gz)
```

But it's showing the following error:

```
/path_to_jni/jni/Android.mk:4: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

How can I make it working? Thank you.

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869349/shell-script-call-from-android-mk-standard-output-and-missing-separator-error

Answer (score 0):

`make` is a rule-based system: a Makefile must specify its actions in the form of rules that describe how to create targets: files, or symbolic targets that merely indicate which rules to execute.
You haven't provided a target.  In this case, your command is not going to produce a single file, so you probably want to use a symbolic target, e.g.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
MY_LOCAL_PATH := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../..

all: $(MY_LOCAL_PATH)/abc.tar.gz
    tar xvzf $<
```

Mind the tab before `tar` (I cannot reproduce it here).